how can I customize my docs that's generate with drf-spectacular for my djoser app
i have and issue to customize any third pkg schema cause i cant access the pkg
is there any solution for this ?
i am using drf_spectacular and djoser and i cant customize social provider endpoint
I am stuck in this bug if anyone can help?
